# How to solve Issubset sum problem if matrix size exceeds limits?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I am trying to practice different questions in competitive coding and was stuck on https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/subset-sum-problem-1611555638/1/# problem.

Below is my solution for it.

```cpp
class Solution{ 
private: 
    long int t[102][100002];
public:
    Solution(){
        memset(t, -1, sizeof(t));
    }
    bool isSubsetSum(int N, int arr[], int sum){
        if(sum == 0 && N ==0) {
            return true;
        } else if(sum == 0) {
            return true;
        } else if(N == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        
        if(t[N][sum] != -1) {
            if(t[N][sum] == 1) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        
        if(arr[N-1] <= sum) {
            bool result = isSubsetSum(N-1, arr, sum- arr[N-1]) || isSubsetSum(N-1, arr, sum);
            t[N][sum] = result ? 1 : 0;
            return result;
        } else {
            t[N][sum] = isSubsetSum(N-1, arr, sum) ? 1 : 0;
            return isSubsetSum(N-1, arr, sum);
        }
        
    }
};
```

It is not working as of now and I'm getting segmentation error for it. If anyone can spot the problem here please help me out.

Below are the examples of input, output and expected output.

```
Example 1:


Input:
N = 6
arr[] = {3, 34, 4, 12, 5, 2}
sum = 9
Output: 1 
Explanation: Here there exists a subset with
sum = 9, 4+3+2 = 9.

Example 2:

Input:
N = 6
arr[] = {3, 34, 4, 12, 5, 2}
sum = 30
Output: 0 
Explanation: There is no subset with sum 30.
```

Below is another solution I tried using vector of maps but it seems to having some sort of syntax error.

```cpp
class Solution{ 
private: 
    // long int t[100][100000];
    vector< map<int, bool> > t(100);
public:
    // Solution(){
    //     memset(t, -1, sizeof(t));
    // }
    bool isSubsetSum(int N, int arr[], int sum){
        if(sum == 0 && N ==0) {
            return true;
        } else if(sum == 0) {
            return true;
        } else if(N == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        
        if(!t[N].empty()) {
            if(t[N][[sum]] == true) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        
        if(arr[N-1] <= sum) {
            bool result = isSubsetSum(N-1, arr, sum- arr[N-1]) || isSubsetSum(N-1, arr, sum);
            t[N][[sum]] = result;
            return result;
        } else {
            bool result = isSubsetSum(N-1, arr, sum);
            t[N][[sum]] = result;
            return result;
        }
        
    }
};
```

Comment: `10^5` is not ten to the power 5

Comment: If I pass in 100002 manually even then I see segmentation fault.

Comment: Please attach a debugger.  Is N liable to be large? Also, is your `Solution` class allocated on the stack or heap? Most OSes give you very limited amounts of stack space.

Comment: where do make sure that you arent going out of bounds of the array? What happens when `N` becomes `< 0` or `sum > 100002` ?

Comment: what is input, output and expected output?

Comment: these are the constraints 
Expected Time Complexity: O(sum*N)
Expected Auxiliary Space: O(sum*N)
 

Constraints:
1 <= N <= 100 

1<= arr[i] <= 100

1<= sum <= 100000

Comment: since the constraints are specified I can be sure that the input will be within this range.

Comment: oh right, you return when `N==0`, didnt see that. Nevertheless, smells like an out-of-bounds access.

Comment: `long int t[102][100002];` -- Just one of those `Solution` instances probably blows out the stack memory.

Comment: added the input, output and expected output examples

Comment: I can solve the problem if I enter 10000 as input but I just wanted to know on how to tackle it when I see the input is larger than that.

Comment: @Nike -- Read my comment.  Why are you declaring arrays so large to begin with?   You are more than likely hitting the stack memory limit.  Think of an alternative to having to declare arrays like that -- no program written should blindly declare gigantic arrays of that size.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie check the ques I made an edit. I added another solution I tried using a vector of maps but it seems to be having some sort of syntax error.

Comment: @Nike *I am trying to practice different questions in competitive coding* -- *it seems to be having some sort of syntax error.* -- So the segmentation fault is gone?  If so, then the issue has moved away from the original problem.

Comment: I don't know if it will have seg fault unless we solve syntax error

Comment: *it seems to be having some sort of syntax error.* -- Where is the syntax error?  Please be more specific.  Second, these "competitive programming" websites goal is not to teach proper C++ -- the questions asked there assume you know the computer language you will be using well enough to never have to ask a question concerning basic language usage.

Comment: vector< map<int, bool> > t(100);

@PaulMcKenzie syntax error is on this line

Comment: [See this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c880f296f18e2730).  That is all you need to  show the issue.  This goes to exactly what I mentioned -- competitive coding websites, and especially the one you are using, just do not teach proper C++, as that is not their goal.  The issue is that you failed to use the member initialization list (basic C++) to initialize the vector.  You don't initialize a vector in the way you guessed.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yeah that's the error I'm getting. Though do you know how I can solve it. I can't see where the code is wrong.

Comment: Use the braces `{ }` or the member-initialization-list of the `Solution` constructor.  You don't use parentheses to initialize a member variable.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like test code creates instance of `Solution` on a stack. Since your class is very big this leads to stackoverflow.

When size of your `t` array is reduced crash is fixed.

Note fixing a crash shows that your solution is invalid (fails on example from task description).

https://godbolt.org/z/GPGjEGMda

Comment: Yeah i know that part but I don't know how to resolve this

Comment: 1. see test I provided and modification I done (note what is in comments) 2. Using test I provided try figure out why your code not passes test (use debugger). 3. My solution passed without problems, but will not provide it, since aim of the task is to learn how to find problems in code you just written.